# Third party facebook login not working in IE8

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am using the following script for Facebook third party login:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       FB.init({
         appId  : '<?=$fbconfig['appid']?>',
         status : true, // check login status
         cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
       });

</script>
```

It's working for all browsers. but it not working in IE8. Kindly help me to solve that issue.

Comment: Any javascript errors?

Comment: With this only code hard to debug and hard to believe :)

Comment: Kindly help yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this asynchronous method many time, I think it may help someone

```
<script>//initializing Facebook API
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
         appId  : '<?=$fbconfig['appid']?>',
         status : true, // check login status
         cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
         xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script><!-- login button --><a href="#" onclick="fblogin();return false;"><img src="images/my_login.png"></a><script>
//your fb login function
function fblogin() {
FB.login(function(response) {
  // you script data
}, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
}
</script>
```